# Kio estas la mallongigo de 'profesoro'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ĉar la mallongigo de 'sinjoro' estas s-ro kaj 'doktoro' estas d-ro, ĉu 'profesoro' estas p-ro?

Mi trovis nur unu enigon pri 'p-ro' en Tekstaro el Zamenhof, 1906.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ĉe la retejo de UEA mi vidis la mallongigon "prof." en la listo de UK-aliĝintoj.

Comment: Tekstaro [seems to support that](https://www.tekstaro.com/?s=5f0f667344408), too.